# Debugging WebMethod()s - stepping into code from the calling project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, web-services, debugging

I used a decompiler to retrieve lost source code for a set of web services written long ago. I want to debug the retrieved web methods using an existing web forms project. The two projects my solution contains are: 1) The recovered web services project and 2) The calling web forms project (created years ago) that references the *live* web services.

I created a project reference from the web forms project to the new web service project. My goal is make temporary changes in the calling code to allow me to step into each WebMethod using the project reference *instead* of the live web service reference. I'm hoping to debug the WebMethods as if I was debugging a standard class library.

The problem is that none of the WebMethods are visible using the project reference. Only the containing class is visible in the calling project but none of the Public Subs or Functions show via intellisense. **How can I debug these WebMethods using the existing calling code from the web forms project?**

Here is one of the simpler calling routines:

```
Private Sub LoadCountryCode()

    Dim liveWebService As New EPriceBookWebService.Service1SoapClient

    'Next line TEMPORARILY commented out for testing...
    'liveWebService.GetCustomerCountry(lstbxCusCodes.SelectedValue, _countryCode)

    'Project reference below shows only the web service class, not the contained public methods via intellisene. WHY?
    EPriceBookService.EPriceBookService.

End Sub
```

Here is the stub of the WebMethod() being called:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Sub GetCustomerCountry(ByVal CusCode As String, ByRef CountryCode As String)
```

Comment: You need to show relevant code of webmethods and the code which calls the webservice

Comment: I solved my problem by replacing the project reference with a web reference to localhost and adding #If DEBUG statements in the calling project. During debug mode I reference the web service on localhost and in release mode I reference the live web service. I'm able to use the debugger to step into the web service project thanks to a setting in the web service property pages (under Web) called "Don’t open a page. Wait for a request from an external application." See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/884653/381082

Comment: @DeveloperDan, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, would you please share the solution as an answer(Not a comment)? So you could mark it as the answer, and then it could help other community members who get the same issue. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here...

It was unwise for me to use a project reference to debug a web service project. Instead, I've learned how to debug the web service project from the calling web forms project (directly stepping into the code). To do this I made use of an obscure setting in the web service project called `"Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application."` You can turn on this setting from the project property pages under the Web category. I learned about [the setting here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/884653/381082) and [here](https://zaagmans.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/dont-open-a-page-wait-for-a-request-from-an-external-application/).

My two projects are in the same solution. The web forms project now references *two* web services 1) the live web service and 2) the localhost web service in my solution. I've added compiler (preprocessor) directives to the web forms project telling it which web service reference to use.

```
#If DEBUG Then
    Dim theWebService As New localhostEPricebookWebReference.EPriceBookService
#Else
    Dim theWebService As New EPriceBookWebService.Service1SoapClient
#End If
```

Be sure you turn off debug mode before deploying your application.